# What are these lists in sklearn tree visualisation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, graphviz, decision-tree

I'm using sklearn.tree.export_graphviz to visualize a decision tree.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.export_graphviz.html

The nodes all have these lists of lists in them and I can't for the life of me figure out what they are or how to get rid of them. First I figured they must be samples. But all the lists are the same size and samples can't be represented as length-2 lists. Then I thought they would be either a representation of the class names, or a representation of impurity, but I've disabled both to no effect. I've also disabled the ID, labels and impurity. It's a multi-class multi-label text classification.

Here's the tree code:

```
def _create_classifier():
    decision_tree_classifier = DecisionTreeClassifier(
    criterion=CRITERION, # Gini
    splitter=SPLITTER,   # best
    min_samples_split=MIN_SAMPLES_SPLIT, # 4
    #max_features=MAX_FEATURES, # 50%
    max_depth=MAX_DEPTH, # 68
    presort=PRESORT # True
    )
return decision_tree_classifier
```

Here's the train and export. Notice everything set to False:

```
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
import os

path = 'dtree.dot'

with open(path, 'w') as dotfile:
     export_graphviz(classifier, out_file = dotfile, feature_names=all_features, filled=True, rounded=True, label=False, class_names=False, node_ids=False, impurity=False, proportion=True)
    print("EXPORTED")
os.system('dot -Tpng dtree.dot -o tree.png')
```

And here be my tree:

[image]

Comment: Hey Neil, how did you get all_features from your estimator?

Comment: @adjective_noun I built all_features up in preprocessing. Basically, just found the vocabulary. It's then converted into a numerical representation at some point.

Comment: Is this "numerical representation" the tfidf features or?

Answer (score 0):

Found it. It is the samples. The representation is the first two components of PCA dimensionality reduction.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/plot_multilabel.html